# Ubuntu 16.04 Triple Monitor on Lenovo W530

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

Wondering if anyone has had any luck with this. Currently, it is working under 14.04, with nvidia-331 and ubuntu-drivers-common_0.2.91.5. Tried https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers, as suggested in [Ubuntu 16.04 dual card triple monitor setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842086/ubuntu-16-04-dual-card-triple-monitor-setup), without any success.

```
lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1000M] (rev a1)
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1556459 and few frustrating hours, here is my solution:
1- Disable PRIME in BIOS
2- Select Discrete Graphics in BIOS
3- Update /etc/default/grub to include
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="thinkpad-acpi.brightness_enable=1 acpi_backlight=vendor"
4- update-grub
5- apt-get remove --purge "nvidia*"
6-Add https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers PPA
7- apt update && apt -y upgrade
8- Select Nouveau as display driver, under Software & Updates, Additional Drivers tab

After reboot, I am able to use LVDS, VGA and DVI. The only snag is that contrast cannot be controlled via keyboard, due to Step 3, above. As a work around, I do:
echo x | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness, where x is between 0 to `cat /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/max_brightness`.
So far, it has been a very good experience, with glxgear showing 60 fps and fan running quieter. 
Cheers,